# How to overload static and dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, g++, smart-pointers

I have a smart pointer class like the below one:

```
template <class T>
class Sptr {
    template<typename U> friend class Sptr;

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    friend bool operator==(const Sptr<T1> &a, const Sptr<T2> &b);
private:
    T* obj;//pointer to current obj
    RC* ref; //reference counter
    std::function<void()> destroyData;
    bool ok_;

public:
    Sptr();
    ~Sptr();

    template <typename U> 
    Sptr(U *);

    Sptr(const Sptr &);

    template <typename U> 
    Sptr(const Sptr<U> &);

    template <typename U> 
    Sptr<T> &operator=(const Sptr<U> &);

    Sptr<T> &operator=(const Sptr<T> &);

    void reset();

    T* operator->() const
    {return obj;};

    T& operator*() const
    {return *obj;};

    T* get() const
    {return obj;};

    explicit operator bool() const {
          return ok_;
    }


};
```

Everything works fine till now and I want to write the function for the `static_pointer_cast` and `dynamic_pointer_cast` . I donot know how to proceed ahead. Could anyone please guide me in the right direction. Below is a sample test code that I intend to pass inorder to test it. (c++11 things ok)

```
// Test static_pointer_cast.
{
    Sptr<Derived> sp(new Derived);
    Sptr<Base1> sp2(sp);

    Sptr<Derived> sp3(static_pointer_cast<Derived>(sp2));
}

// Test dynamic_pointer_cast.
{
    Sptr<Derived_polymorphic> sp(new Derived_polymorphic);
    Sptr<Base_polymorphic> sp2(sp);

    Sptr<Derived_polymorphic> sp3(dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived_polymorphic>(sp2));
    Sptr<Derived_polymorphic> sp4(static_pointer_cast<Derived_polymorphic>(sp2));
    Sptr<Derived2_polymorphic> sp5(dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived2_polymorphic>(sp2));
    assert(!sp5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both casts are templates (probably friends) that create a new `Sptr` of a different type initialized with a cast to the underlying pointer and increment the reference count as needed. The main complication is that you need multiple pointers of different types to the same complete object and you need to manage calling the deleter with the correct pointer when the last one (of whichever type it is) goes out of scope.

A possible approach is storing the deleter and the original pointer inside the reference count object (BTW, the deleter should have always been there, you only need one copy!). Each Sptr holds a raw pointer of different types, but when it goes away it uses the pointer stored in the reference count with the deleter.